# ASP.NET MVC Non English URL Request Validation Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, httpwebrequest

In my ASP.NET MVC 2 application, I have this encoded image url -

```
<img src="/Image?Selected_Nme=Mayag%26%23252%3Bez%2C%20PR/>
```

The uncoded Selected_Nme is "Mayagüez, PR".

I will get an exception error like this -

```
[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (amp;Selected_Nme="Mayag&#252;ez, PR").]
```

Then I decorated my action in controller with "[ValidateInput(false)]", like this -

```
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [HttpGet]
        [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "test")]
        public ActionResult Image(string Selected_Nme = ""){
...
}
```

I still see the same error after this.

What can I do to eliminate the problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the `requestValidationMode`:

```
<system.Web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

From [Request Validation in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh882339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> You can disable request validation for an entire application, but
>   doing so is not recommended. The recommendation is to selectively
>   disable request validation only for the virtual paths or specific
>   pages where you want to allow markup.
>
> In either case, you must make two changes in the Web.config file. The
>   first change is to set the requestValidationMode attribute of the
>   httpRuntime element to "2.0". This setting makes request validation
>   occur later in the sequence of request processing events. **The setting
>   is required for applications that use ASP.NET 4 and later, because as
>   of ASP.NET 4, request validation takes place earlier in the request
>   life cycle than it did in previous versions of ASP.NET**

One last worthwhile note.  Using `[ValidateInput(false)]` disables validation for **all** data sent into the method.  If you would still like to keep validation in place for any other properties being sent, you can disable the validation on a specific property of a class:

```
public class SomeModel {
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Selected_Nme { get; set; }

    // this property will still be validated!
    public string PleaseDontXSSMe { get; set; }
}
```